# how to get localhost to work correctly again on Lion

Tags: macos, networking, osx-lion, localhost

Anything that asks for something via localhost fails. I can't get any result from pinging localhost. The only way I can reach anything in my network would be to resort to connecting to my externalIP:port# and that will route myself back in.
My host file seems to look ok... How can I fix this?

Comment: Does it seem to look okay or *is it* okay? You post it here? Has it ever worked? Do you remember changing anything?

Comment: does ping 127.0.0.1 work?

Comment: well, it was where I could delete my preferences folder out of my system level Library and reboot and I could then ping 127.0.0.1 and localhost successfully. now when I reboot doing the same I can only ping 127.0.0.1 and localhost is still "ping: cannot resolve localhost: Unknown host"

Comment: also I tried deleting my hosts file to let the OS re create it and issue persists

Answer (score 0):

Are you 100% sure your host file is correct?

If ping is giving you Unknown host that means it doesn't have that info on the host files or any thing to resolve to localhost being your computer.

Open a terminal window

Type in 
    sudo pico /private/etc/hosts

Check if you have something like this

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
```

If you don't have this lines (which you probably don't by the result of your ping) then your host file is not ok.

You need those lines, specially the first one to be able to resolve to localhost.